# Get the selected subitem in a listview

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to find the selected SubItem of a ListView.

I have a ListView with the following properties

```
View = Details
FullRowSelect = True
GridLines = True
ShowItemToolTips =  True
MultiSelect = False
```

I then add 3 columns and multiple rows, each with 2 subitems to populate each of the columns. I end up with a ListView looking something like this

```
Header1   | Header2    | Header3
==========+============+===========
Item 1    | Sub1Item1  | Sub2Item1
Item 2    | Sub1Item2  | Sub2Item2
Item 3    | Sub1Item3  | Sub2Item3
```

If I hover over a particular item, say Sub2Item2 it will give me the appropriate ToolTip "Sub2Item2". However I want to catch an event either a mouse click or a mouse hover and get the associated SubItem so I can use it's Tag property to do further processing.

I have checked the args for ItemMouseHover() event and can't find anything to do this, nor can I after searching around online.

[Edit to clarify] I am trying to hook an event such as SelectedIndexChange or MouseUp  (any mouse click related event is fine) and **get the current selected SubItem**. Think of it like a spreadsheet, when I click a cell (SubItem) I want to get the cell itself (SubItem) not the entire row (ListViewItem)

Comment: Its not clear what actually you want? did you try something?

Comment: I want to be able to say, click a particular row in the details ListView and somehow retreive the SubItem that I clicked on. The only object I seem to be given by any event args is the ListViewItem itself not the SubItem under the mouse when the event fires. This is the same for any event, hover, click etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [ListView.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8ssfa8a.aspx) method is what you're looking for.

Comment: This answer, in combo with having the property of fullrowselect = true is what did it for me. + 1

Answer (score 0):

In your case [**`SelectedItems`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx) property should work until Hover comes into consideration. for hover event there is a property called [**`HoverSelection`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hoverselection.aspx).